# Question from elementary algebra I'm having trouble with

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, fractions

If 1/3 be added to the numerator of a certain fraction the fraction will be increased by 1/21, and if 1/2 be taken from the denominator the fraction becomes 8/9: find it.

```
  As per my understanding the conditions that can be applied from the information given in the question is let x/y be the fraction, then 

 (X+(1/3))/y = (x/y)+(1/21)......first eqn.
 x/(y-(1/2)) = 8/9.......second eqn.
```

Please point out how to proceed from here or correct me if there are any mistakes.
The answer is given at the end of the question to be 3/14, and this question is supposed to be of 2 equation 2 variables but the first equation by itself gives the values of both x and y so I'm confused whether what I'm doing is wrong or whether there's a flaw in the question itself

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This question has an unfortunate mixing between rational numbers and fractions. Usually the two terms can be used interchangeably, but when explicitly manipulating the numerator and the denominator, you need to be careful. Most importantly, is the original fraction assumed to be written in lowest terms?

Comment: Yes I think the original fraction is assumed to be written in the lowest terms

Answer (score 0):

If u take the first eq. and then take LCM on RHS,

```
[x+(1/3)]/y = [x+(y/21)]/y          [the y's on the denominator cancel out]
x+(1/3) = x+(y/21)                  [the x's cancel out]
1/3 = y/21                          [multiply 21 on both sides]
y = 7                               [substitute in eq. 2]
```

```
x/[y-(1/2)] = 8/9
x/[7-(1/2)] = 8/9
x/[13/2] = 8/9                       [multiply 13/2 on both sides]
x = 52/9
```

The fraction is `x/y = (52/9)/7 = 52/(9*7) = 52/63`
Therefore, the fraction is `52/63`

Comment: Thank you for attempting erm yeah I also got that but I've done that but it is showing the answer is supposed to be 3/14 I'm not sure why that is why I'm confused